# Is having a lot of data fields a bad thing?

Tags: java, field

In Java, is having ~50 data fields in a class of about 1000 lines a bad thing?

**Edit:** Thanks for the feedback. Has really opened my eyes and I'll try to delegate functionality across more classes rather than have a single do-everything class. :)

Comment: We would need some code to even begin to make a decision.

Comment: I understand that now. I think I've sussed what I need to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is very vague. The answer can be both yes and no. Yes, it's a bad thing if you can break the functionality cleanly into more classes. No, it's not a bad thing if the class is well focused and the only reason you got 50 fields is because you NEED them all there.

I have, for example, a class of 900 lines with 70 fields, but that's because the class implements a bit of artificial intelligence and the parameters the AI algorithm uses are a lot of behaviors and thresholds which need to be defined there so that child classes tweak them. In my case, I would say that it's not a bad architecture, and my 14 years of software development seem to agree ::- ).

Sure, if the class would go over 1000 lines, I could break it down further into 2: movement AI and attack AI, but for now, it really makes sense in the context of my project to have it together because movement AI and attack AI are never applied independently: they work together, they should be in the same class. If I ever have to make an object which ONLY needs movement AI, then by all means, I'd break it apart into 2.

Comment: Tough question. We would need some code samples to even begin to answer it ::- ).

Comment: +1 for good answer (although I secretly desire your untimely demise for writing a 900 line class).

Comment: Actually I admit I could break it in 2 but it's not THAT serious (I could split the artificial intelligence in 2 parts - movement & attacking). You can always break stuff in more pieces, but sometimes this may lead to another problem: class fragmentation. If you think I invented that, it's because I did. It's when you break up your code so much that you actually make it less manageable. I try to not be swayed by some of the more radical trends in software such as "a class may have no more than 10 fields" (Code Complete). If you end up with too many classes, it's just as bad.

Answer (score 4):

from Code Complete:

> Be critical of classes that contain more than about seven data members:The number "7±2" has been found to be a number of discrete items a person can remember        while performing other tasks (Miller 1956). If a class contains more than about seven        data members, consider whether the class should be decomposed into multiple smaller        classes (Riel 1996). You might err more toward the high end of 7±2 if the data members        are primitive data types like integers and strings, more toward the lower end of 7±2 if        the data members are complex objects.

Comment: I think this is greatly exaggerated. 9 fields is insane. You may get to a situation when you got TOO MANY classes and then, again, it's bad ::- ). I think you need to find balance in your project, not obsessively follow some rules some dude wrote 30 years ago when software development was a lot different.

Comment: Of course it is a rule of thumb that is not intended to be strictly accurate or reliable for every situation. However, in most cases it helps to evaluate the design.

Comment: Agreed, this is foolish. The number of fields should be guided by the principle of cohesion, not some arbitrary figure based on how much people can remember.

Comment: The other problem is that if you stick to such rules with obsession, you may end up with too many classes and then its worse ::- ).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a code smell and will make your code harder to read and modify. Your class will become a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

[Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html) has a nice article on them, all of us should read it.

Comment: God Object. Didn't know that one, it's a nice nomenclature. But be careful, not all "big classes" are code smells. Programming is very much like architecture: to build a big building, you sometimes need large concrete slabs, not only little screws and furniture ::- ).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds bad, but who knows. You may actually have found an object that requires 50 fields, all of which are interrelated and required to be in the one object.

If not, and to stay sane, try to split it up into smaller parts where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Short story; yes. Long story; this is very subjective. A class with 1000 lines seems very excessive. Are all those fields really related? A class should be focused (exhibit high cohesion). Try splitting your fields into smaller, more tightly focused classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bad thing is to have a class about 1000 lines... Try to refactor it to do it smaller if it possible...

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, but it often means that your class should be seperated into several classes as it is doing to many things or your class takes on responsibilities that should be in other classes.  It depends on your application's design.